# Why is CoreData not linking in my ported iOS->Mac App?

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, core-data, linker

I'm porting an app from the iOS side to the Mac side and I'm having an annoying linking error where the linker appears to be trying to use the iOS version of the coredata framework instead of the (x86_64) one. I've deleted the framework and re-added it and know I'm adding the mac version. I've also regenerated my model classes. I'm getting this error:

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xxxxx/xcode_projects/xxxxx/CoreData.framework/CoreData, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
     Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
     "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
     -[CoreDataSingleton persistentStoreCoordinator] in CoreDataSingleton.o
     "_NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption", referenced from:
     -[CoreDataSingleton persistentStoreCoordinator] in CoreDataSingleton.o
     "_NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption", referenced from:
     -[CoreDataSingleton persistentStoreCoordinator] in CoreDataSingleton.o
     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in CoreDataSingleton.o
     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in CoreDataSingleton.o

     etc...

     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64


     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks,

Nick

Comment: I recreated the project and that seemed to fix the linking error

Comment: Actually this didn't work as soon as I started using the coredata singleton class it pooped in the same manner as before so I guess im still screwed. I though it may have had something to do with doing a forward declaration on the singleton for the app delegate so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: check that last bit I was building the older project, lol. it is running but I have more issues to deal with that I beleieve are unrelated to this original issue so I'm considering this solved.

Answer (score 13):

Link errors usually mean you aren't including a framework in the project.

In the "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the "Build Phases" tab of the build settings for your project, make sure CoreData.framework is listed. If not, press the "+" button and select it.[image]

Comment: Hey thanks I had definitely included the coredata.framework I think what happened was for some dumb reason I initially dragged in the framework from the ios project to the mac project and for whatever reason it did not make the transition to the new architecture. Even after removing and re-adding it still was attempting to link the ios version of coredata and not the mac version.